# Pipe result of find into variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am wanting to transfer the result of a find command into a variable named 'String3', as below;

```
Set String3=0

for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do 
echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String3Search%">nul | ( !String3! )
```

However i get the following error;

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

The index contains the number of open websites within Internet Explorer. So the find is determining if the 'String3Search' exists.

Where am i going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and find out what is wrong with your syntax...

Comment: You will need a second nested `FOR` command to capture the result of the `FIND` command.

Comment: @Squashman How would this look like? Apologies, i have attempted to read online, but each article suggests finding files, whereas i am working with index and websites.

Comment: @aschipfl My syntax is correct, as i believe I am using command extensions. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Uhujkill, no your code is not correct.  In order for the `ECHO` command to work on a separate line, you need to use parentheses.  I will update your code in my answer.

Comment: Ah, apologies guys. My bad, I've been editing my code, and must have eliminated the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FOR /F` command to capture the result of other commands you are running. Also note the use of parentheses.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "String3=0"
set "String3Search=findme"

for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do ( 
    FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('echo !URL[%%i]! ^| find /I "%String3Search%"') DO (
        set "String3=%%G"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It works, and I will keep this format in mind should it come up again. Thanks again.